# Order or function/list arguments in map/select/others

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I keep being uncertain of the correct order of `[function,expr]` arguments to functions such as Select, Pick, Cases, Position, etc., because I'm used to the `[f, expr]` order from the `Map` family of functions.

1. Is there a good rule of thumb to remember which order should be used where?
2. More importantly, is there a good reason that the Map family has it opposite to the rest? Incidentally this may help with 1 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `Map` is the exception. I would read

```
 Map[f,list]
```

as "map `f` over `list`". Same for

```
 Apply[f  x]
```

meaning "apply `f` to `x".

In contrast, I would read

```
Select[list,list]
```

as "select from `list` by (selector) `f`. The same applies to `Pick`. But have to idea for `Cases` and `Position`, basically because they are no verbs.

Comment: I understand the structure of the Map sentence (and actually the Map family is the one where I don't confuse the order). However, I'm unclear on why "Select from `list` by `f`" is more natural than "Select by `f` from `list`. Perhaps SQL `SELECT` statement should be the guide here, since the `WHERE` clause comes after the data clause there as well.